# Heroku scheduler not running hourly

Tags: heroku, cron

I used heroku scheduler to automate tasks but it seems it's not working as it described 
see this
[image]

although the frequency is set to hourly

the interval between last run and next due is 5 hours

what's going on here?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: Having the same issue as well.. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i just had to create another task, hourly from the beginning, and it worked. The old schedule was removed as the new one started to work.